# Spring Data Elastic and recursive document mapping

Tags: java, recursion, spring-data, stack-overflow, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Spring application where I use Spring Data Elastic for accessing Elasticsearch data.

The data model requires recursion and it causes headache for Spring Data Elastic, because I got *java.lang.StackOverflowError: null*, when trying to run my app.

This is how my class looks like:

```
@Document(indexName = "conversation", type = "folder-tree")
public class MailFolderTreeSearchEntity extends DeletableEntity {

  @Id
  @Field(index = not_analyzed)
  private String id;

  @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
  private String owner;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
  private List<MailFolder> folderList;

  ...
```

The nested class:

```
public class MailFolder {

  @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
  private String id;

  @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
  private String name;

  @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
  private String icon;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
  private List<MailFolder> children;

  ...
```

and this is the exception I get, when trying to run the code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:310) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:283) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeArgument(SignatureParser.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeArguments(SignatureParser.java:396) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parsePackageNameAndSimpleClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:346) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:310) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:289) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:283) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:485) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSig(SignatureParser.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository.parse(FieldRepository.java:52) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository.parse(FieldRepository.java:42) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.AbstractRepository.<init>(AbstractRepository.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository.<init>(FieldRepository.java:48) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository.make(FieldRepository.java:66) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericInfo(Field.java:105) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericType(Field.java:247) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$FieldTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:285) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:150) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1333) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forField(ResolvableType.java:1053) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.GenericCollectionTypeResolver.getCollectionFieldType(GenericCollectionTypeResolver.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.getFieldType(MappingBuilder.java:321) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.isEntity(MappingBuilder.java:312) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.mapEntity(MappingBuilder.java:132) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.mapEntity(MappingBuilder.java:137) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.mapEntity(MappingBuilder.java:137) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.mapEntity(MappingBuilder.java:137) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.MappingBuilder.mapEntity(MappingBuilder.java:137) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "The data model requires recursion" - there is no notion of recursive mapping in ES, so don't expect the library to support that.

Comment: Maybe I was using the wrong terminology, but I hope the task is clear: I want to store documents that can store the same type of documents within themselves. Is that possible at all, or not?

Comment: It is possible, except you cannot use any Java-level recursion do define that mapping. You need to have a finite mapping, by copy pasting your definitions. Or switch to dynamic mapping, I don't know if Spring data supports that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many days of research, I found the solution, so I wanted to share it with the community, maybe it will be useful for someone else as well.

To avoid the StackOverflowExpcetion, when the Spring Data Elasticsearch tries to map your recursive schema, you have to use the `ignoreFields` attribute within the `@Field` annotation, so the mapper will not go into an infinite loop.

This is how my *MailFolder* class looks at the moment:

```
...
public class MailFolder {

@Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
private String id;

@Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
private String name;

@Field(type = FieldType.String, index = not_analyzed)
private String icon;

@Field(type = FieldType.Boolean, index = not_analyzed)
private boolean system;

@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, ignoreFields = {"children"})
private List<MailFolder> children;
...
```

Comment: I am using ES 7.6.2. When I am trying to use recursive nesting, the index gets created but the mappings is empty. Tried using your solution too, but I am still not able to generate mapping